# WSO2 inboundEndpoint trying to parse file as XML despite transport.vfs.ContentType="text/csv"

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When trying to use File inboundEndpoint in WSO2 5.0.0 to process an inbound csv file I'm always getting an exception as if WSO2 is trying to parse the file as XML despite the fact tat I've set the **transport.vfs.ContentType** parameter to "text/csv" in the inboundEndpoint configuration:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/csv</parameter>
```

Here's the full stack error I'm getting:

```
[2016-10-08 16:56:31,181] ERROR - FileInjectHandler Error while processing the file/folder
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'i' (code 105) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createStAXSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createSOAPModelBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:196)
    at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FileInjectHandler.invoke(FileInjectHandler.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.processFile(FilePollingConsumer.java:763)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.directoryHandler(FilePollingConsumer.java:543)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.poll(FilePollingConsumer.java:214)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FilePollingConsumer.execute(FilePollingConsumer.java:134)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.FileTask.taskExecute(FileTask.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.common.InboundTask.execute(InboundTask.java:45)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

And here's the full configuration for the inboundEndpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="BigBuyCategoryMapper" protocol="file" sequence="ProcessCategoryMapper" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/csv</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///Users/gamac/temp/in</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///Users/gamac/temp/failed</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">mapper_category.csv</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///Users/gamac/temp/done</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute">none</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAscending">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using text/plain instead of text/csv seems to get around this issue:

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
```

However the proper solution is probably to configure a Message Builder/Formatter for text/csv as per WSO2 documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters